# Part of PHP only runs if the form is submitted twice

Tags: php, html

In a very basic login page I set up an error status to show if the form was submitted with an empty pin or an invalid pin was entered but it only functions if I submit the form twice with the same error.

Where am I going wrong here?
Or else what would be  a better way to achieve this?

```
<?php

if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Page Title</h1>

<div class="smallcontainer">
  <form method="post" action="">
    
    <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-20">
        <label for="id">Driver Pin</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-80">
        <input type="text" name="id" >
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-100 error">
            <?= @$_SESSION['status'] ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-100">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
        </div>
    </div>
    
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    
    $id = trim($_POST['id']);
        
    if (empty($_POST['id'])){
    $_SESSION['status'] = 'Enter a Driver Pin';
    }
    
    // if (!strlen($id)) {
    // $_SESSION['status'] = 'Enter a Driver Pin';
    // //die('Please enter Driver Pin');
    // }
    
    $success = false;
        
    $handle = fopen("users.csv", "r");
        
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
        if ($data[0] == $id) {
        $success = true;
        $_SESSION['displayname'] = $data[1];
        break;
        } 
    }
    
    fclose($handle);
    
    if ($success) {
        $_SESSION['allow'] = '';
        header('Location: ./');
    } else {
        $_SESSION['status'] = 'Invalid Driver Pin - Try again';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Could be your session check. Try using `session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to put the php before the form (as already said) and here is your code with a few fixes:

```
<?php

if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
}



if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $id = trim($_POST['id']);

        $success = false;

        $handle = fopen("users.csv", "r");

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
                if ($data[0] == $id) {
                $success = true;
                $_SESSION['displayname'] = $data[1];
                break;
                }
        }

        fclose($handle);

        if ($success) {
                $_SESSION['allow'] = '';
                $_SESSION['status'] = 'Success!';
                /*header('Location: ./');*/
        } else {
                if (empty($_POST['id'])){
                    $_SESSION['status'] = 'Enter a Driver Pin';
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['status'] = 'Invalid Driver Pin - Try again';
                }

        }
} else {
    $_SESSION['status'] = 'Enter a Driver Pin';
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">

<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Page Title</h1>

<div class="smallcontainer">
    <form method="post" action="">

        <div class="row">

                <div class="col-20">
                <label for="id">Driver Pin</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-80">
                <input type="text" name="id" >
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-100 error">
                        <?= @$_SESSION['status'] ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-100">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
                </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This will work - notice I added an else if there is no post on fresh load you need to reset the $_SESSION['status'];

Answer (score 0):

You php that checks and set status is located after HTML, which means the HTML returned by the page submission will not have the status updated until next submission.

So, move your PHP code above HTML.

Also, you can't use `header()` after anything was printed out already.